# [Java]Nested if else statement + Multiple System.out.print commands

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, println

I need some help with figuring out why this doesn't work. Is it possibly just a rule for nested if-else statements or if-else statements in general to only allow one System.out.print Statement?
I need it to output 
"Probably has seat belts. 
Probably has anti-lock brakes."

And so on once it gets to 2000.

The code:

```
public class CarFeatures {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int carYear = 0;

      carYear = 1990;

      if (carYear <= 1969) {
         System.out.println("Probably has few safety features.");

      }else{
         if (carYear >= 1970) {
            System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");

         }else{
            if (carYear >= 1990) {
               System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");
               System.out.println("Probably has anti-lock brakes.");

         }else{
             if (carYear >= 2000) {
               System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");
               System.out.println("Probably has anti-lock brakes.");
               System.out.println("Probably has air bags.");

             }
            }
         }
      }
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because this

```
 if (carYear >= 1970) {
        System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");

     }else{

     }
```

1990>1970,so just println "Probably has seat belts."

Answer (score 0):

By having `if{...} else {...}` the `else will not be entered into if the`if` is true

so remove them

```
 if {
    ...
 }else{
     if (carYear >= 1970) {
        System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");

     }
     if (carYear >= 1990) {
           System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");
           System.out.println("Probably has anti-lock brakes.");

     }
      if (carYear >= 2000) {
           System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");
           System.out.println("Probably has anti-lock brakes.");
           System.out.println("Probably has air bags.");

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because `1990` is greater than or equal to `1990` but it is also greater than or equal to `1970`. Because the `1970` statement occurs first in the code it never reaches the `1990` statement.

To fix this there are various optimizations that can occur in your code:

1. You can declare and initilize `carYear` to `1990` on one line.
2. Use if statements instead of else statements in the nested level to not have to duplicate print statements.

Try the below code [here!](https://repl.it/G5Wi/1)

```
public class CarFeatures {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    int carYear = 1990;

    if (carYear <= 1969) {
      System.out.println("Probably has few safety features.");
    } else {
      if (carYear >= 1970) {
        System.out.println("Probably has seat belts.");
      } 
      if (carYear >= 1990) {
        System.out.println("Probably has anti-lock brakes.");
      }
      if (carYear >= 2000) {
        System.out.println("Probably has air bags.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```